# How I can compute power and traffic for each vm to do accounting for client?

Tags: maas

I've installed MAAS cloud but nothing do with accounting... If I'm going to use it as a public cloud PXE boot from client. How I can compute power and traffic for each vm to do accounting for client?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can compute power for individual VMs, but one way to compute power for the entire rack is to install an intelligent `PDU` that allows `SNMP management`. For a vendor specific example, see here:

http://www.dell.com/us/enterprise/p/dell-pdu

A generic description of PDUs:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_distribution_unit

As for `MAAS cloud` can you be a bit more specific like provide a URL? Most cloud products support some kind of SNMP management so you could for example enable SNMP on the interface and then run an accounting program against the SNMP statistics. One example would be PRTG with it's billing API:

http://www.paessler.com/blog/2011/01/31/prtg-8/billing-tool-for-prtg-version-10-released

We've succesfully installed this in our environment but it's quite specific and had to be customized (we needed a Web/PHP developer to get it going).

Another way to account for traffic would be to use a Netflow collector and enable Netflow on the interfaces (if `MAAS Cloud` supports this).